# HttpRequestValidationException redirecting to login page (forms authentication)

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, validation

In .NET 4.0 request validation was stepped up a notch!  It seems when any code tries to access Request.Form, the values within the form are validated, and a HttpRequestValidationException is thrown.

This in itself shouldn't be a problem, except that I've found a particular scenario where ASP.NET itself is certainly not doing me any favours in dealing with this situation.

I have a form which accepts HTML input (I'd rather not, but I do, OK?).  The edit model for this form has the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on the field, so submitting HTML is fine and does not throw the exception.

However, if the user is not authenticated (for example, their session timed out) and they try to submit the form, a HttpRequestValidationException is thrown while ASP.NET is trying to redirect to the login page.  The exception is thrown when ASP.NET is verifying whether the request is an AJAX request or not, at which point it tries to access a form field.

Stack trace:

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (LongDescription="<p>Hello</p>").]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +8855748
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateNameValueCollection(NameValueCollection nvc, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +122
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +150
   System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Form() +11
   System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.IsAsyncPostBackRequest(HttpRequestBase request) +223
   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.HttpResponse_Redirecting(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent) +394
   System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +9044409
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Offending lines of code within `System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.IsAsyncPostBackRequest`:

```
// DevDiv Bugs 188713: X-MicrosoftAjax header is stripped by some firewalls 
string asyncPost = request.Form[AsyncPostFormField];
return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(asyncPost) && (asyncPost.Trim() == "true");
```

All I would like is for it to successfully redirect to the login page in this scenario.  I'd also like to NOT disable .NET 4.0 validation!

Anyone got any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously having problem with "<p>Hello</p>".

You can set validateRequest="false" in Page directive in aspx, but this will effectively disable page validation and could be harmful for the server / db ( can be attacked easily ).

To avoid this, look for some JS UrlEncoding of this value before the page is sent to server, or disable page validation ( validateRequest ) and handle user input before working with it -

string safe = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode( someTextbox.Text );

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647397.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but applying UrlEncoding to HTML wouldn't be right - it would have to be HTML encoding (for example, & in URL encoding is %26 but in HTML is &amp;.  Also I would need this to apply to ALL forms that allow HTML - only to cater for the one situation where it is redirecting to the login page...

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this on ASP.NET forum as well to see if we can get a response.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1791239.aspx/1?HttpRequestValidationException+redirecting+to+login+page+forms+authentication+